# Laravel no reconoce último id en tabla Postgress despues de insertarle datos por import desde un csv

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, csv, pgadmin

Tengo una base de datos postgress a la cual le inserte unos datos por import con un ecxell,cada tabla tiene su campo ****id autoincrement**,** hasta aqui todo normal, hasta que desde laravel al insertar datos a cualquier tabla lo intenta hacer con el **id 1** sabiendo que ya hay datos en la tabla y ya va en el registro 56 por ejemplo

Comment: Podrias compartir una parte de tu codigo de como hacer el import y en como haces el insert de los datos de solo ingresa el 1.

Comment: el import simplemente lo hago con pgadmin4,y el error es tal cual lo describo en el problema

Comment: si tu en tabla de postgress tu id es autoincrementable, desde laravel no deberias de insertar ningun id, porque tu tabla ya hace ese trabajo, pero si muestras el codigo, sera un poco mas entendible

Answer (score 2):

Por defecto, hay una función **increments()** para setear auto_increment:

```
Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    // ... more fields
});
```

Pero no hay ninguna función o método para hacer algo como:

```
$table->increments('id')->start_from(140000);
```

Así que hay dos opciones para esto, las dos implican interactuar con la base de datos después de haber creado el esquema inicial.

**Opción 1**

Luego del **Schema::create()**, ejecutar un SQL para cambiar el valor de auto_increment:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            // ... more fields
        });

        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE books AUTO_INCREMENT = 14000;");
    }
```

**Opción 2**

Si eliminamos un registro, el valor de auto_increment va a iniciar desde esta posición, así que se puede hacer algo como esto:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            // ... more fields
        });

        DB::table('books')->insert(['id' => 13999, 'name' => 'whatever']);
        DB::table('books')->where('id', 13999)->delete();
    }
```

Comment: "ALTER TABLE books AUTO_INCREMENT = 14000;" esto no es reconocido por postgress

Comment: Tienes razón, para postgress debería ser DB::statement(“ALTER SEQUENCE $table_$primarykey_seq MINVALUE 0 START 0 RESTART 0”); en tu caso como pusiste en la respuesta de abajo creo que es correcto

Answer (score 1):

Buscando encontré que Postgress maneja lo que son las **Sequences**, cuando en Laravel se crea un campo autoincrement lo que hace es crear una Secuencia en postgress que, el nombre de la sequencia es el nombre de la tabla concatenado el campo autiincrement y al final la palabra seq, un ejemplo  tabla cleintes , id autoincrement, en postgress se creó  client_id_seq

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al subir un archivo csv estas secuencias no se modifican, por lo que están en cero, y Laravel consulta es la secuencia, por lo tanto si con el archivo csv por ejemplo subiste 55 registros a la tabla clients debe setear la secuencia al siguiente

**ALTER SEQUENCE client_id_seq RESTART 56;**